# Unable to resize JPanel in java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I just started using Java Swing, and I was going through the following post: [Dynamic fields addition in java/swing form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587837/dynamic-fields-addition-in-java-swing-form).
I implement the code in this post with some modification, and it worked fine. As mentioned in the post, `JPanel` is not resizing itself when we add more rows. Can someone throw more light on this issue with easy to understand explanation that how can we resize `JPanel` as soon as we hit +/- button? Here is the code :

**Row class**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Row extends JPanel {

    private JTextField quantity;
    private JTextField item;
    private JTextField price;
    private JButton plus;
    private JButton minus;
    private RowList parent;

    public Row(String initialQuantity, String initalPrice, String initialItem, RowList list) {
        this.parent = list;
        this.plus = new JButton(new AddRowAction());
        this.minus = new JButton(new RemoveRowAction());
        this.quantity = new JTextField(10);
        this.item = new JTextField(10);
        this.price = new JTextField(10);
        this.quantity.setText(initialQuantity);
        this.price.setText(initalPrice);
        this.item.setText(initialItem);
        add(this.plus);
        add(this.minus);
        add(this.quantity);
        add(this.item);
        add(this.price);
    }

    public class AddRowAction extends AbstractAction {

        public AddRowAction() {
            super("+");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            parent.cloneRow(Row.this);
        }
    }

    public class RemoveRowAction extends AbstractAction {

        public RemoveRowAction() {
            super("-");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            parent.removeItem(Row.this);
        }
    }

    public void enableAdd(boolean enabled) {
        this.plus.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    public void enableMinus(boolean enabled) {
        this.minus.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

**RowList class**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class RowList extends JPanel{
        private List<Row> rows;

        public RowList() {
            this.rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
            Row initial = new Row("1","0.00","", this);
            //addHeaders();
            //addGenerateBillButton();
            addItem(initial);
        }

        public void addHeaders(){
            JLabel qty = new JLabel("Quantity");
            //qty.setBounds(10, 0, 80, 25);
            add(qty);
            JLabel item = new JLabel("Item");
            //item.setBounds(70, 0, 80, 25);
            add(item);
            JLabel price = new JLabel("Price");
            //price.setBounds(120, 0, 80, 25);
            add(price);
        }

        public void addGenerateBillButton(){
            JButton billGenerationButton = new JButton("Generate Bill");
            add(billGenerationButton);
        }

        public void cloneRow(Row row) {
            Row theClone = new Row("1","0.00","", this);
            addItem(theClone);
        }

        private void addItem(Row row) {
            rows.add(row);
            add(row);
            refresh();
        }

        public void removeItem(Row entry) {
            rows.remove(entry);
            remove(entry);
            refresh();
        }

        private void refresh() {
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            if (rows.size() == 1) {
                rows.get(0).enableMinus(false);
            }
            else {
                for (Row e : rows) {
                    e.enableMinus(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Main class**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Enter Items");
        RowList panel = new RowList();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
 }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).  From the sounds of it, the OP on the quoted question chose buggy code over the better answer of camickr..

Comment: after adding/removing just call revalidate(); repaint() of the container pane

Comment: it appears this has no effect :(

Comment: Actually, the panel **does try to resize itself**. The issue is simply that a window does not resize itself automatically, so the new rows are outside visible area. If you place the panel inside a `JScrollPane`, you'll see it grow automatically (though as the layout is `FlowLayout`, the "rows" will be added horizontally).

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5760093/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `pack()` of the frame again.

Try this: Add this in your **Row** class

```
    public class AddRowAction extends AbstractAction
    {

        public AddRowAction()
        {
            super("+");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            parent.cloneRow(Row.this);

            ((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(parent)).pack(); // <--- THIS LINE
        }
    }

    public class RemoveRowAction extends AbstractAction
    {

        public RemoveRowAction()
        {
            super("-");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            parent.removeItem(Row.this);

            ((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(parent)).pack(); // <--- THIS LINE
        }
    }
```

You can get the root component (JFrame) using the `SwingUtilities.getRoot(comp)` from the `child` component and call the `pack()` method after your new **Row** is added to your **RowList**.

This would resize your JPanel. But your **RowList** will be horizontal. This is where **LayoutManager** comes into play.

You can know more about different `LayoutManagers` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

To fix this problem, in your **RowList** panel, set your layout to:

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Answer (score -1):

Within your refresh method call ***doLayout()*** method after ***revalidate()***